# How to set equal height for 2 position:absolute divs?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs with `position:absolute` set, looking as such:

```
#nav {
position:absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
}

#content {
position: absolute;
width: 70%:
height: 100%;
}
```

The `#content` div often exceeds the pages size, requiring the user to scroll down.

But the `#nav` div stops at the bottom of the screen - it does not continue down the page as the user scrolls.

Is there any way to make both divs have equal height (without JQuery)?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? There may be a solution but it depends on the details of the mark-up.

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning? Absolute positioning takes the elements out of the regular content flow, which means that the `#nav` cannot know the height of the `#content` block, so cannot adjust the height to match.  If you can't alter the HTML/CSS, then you will need jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css tables. (but you'll have to remove `position:absolute`)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/nzDxj/2/)**

### Markup

```
<div id="css-table">
    <div class="col narrow">some content</div>
    <div class="col wide">content</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#css-table { 
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
#css-table .col { 
    display: table-cell; 
    padding: 10px; 
}
.narrow
{
    background: lime;
}
.wide
{
    background:aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a fixed positioning over the #nav.
So, instead of position: absolute;
try position: fixed only for the first div, i.e. #nav. This should make it always be on the screen no matter how much the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

try these css

```
#nav {
position:absolute;
width: 300px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
margin-bottom: -99999px;
}

#content {
position: absolute;
width: 70%:
padding-bottom: 99999px;
margin-bottom: -99999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OP has not accepted any answer, m trying my luck.... :)
I think the **fault is in line** `width: 70%:` for `#content`....there is `:` instead of `;`...i tried your code here after replacing it in fiddle and looks fine to me :

**Fiddle :**  http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/LDh5x/2/

HTML remaining the same, here is the **CSS**

```
#nav {
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #000; //to show the different divs
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
}

#content {
position: absolute;
width: 70%; //this was mistake point
height: 100%;
text-align:right; //to show the text
border:1px solid #CCC;  //to show the different divs
}
```